# Stability of super vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles

A super vector bundle is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded bundle, see for example "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators" of Berline-Vergne-Getzler section 1.3.

Does it exist an adapted notion of stability for such bundles?